# Coupon Code is always assigned, even if not displayed

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

Our client is looking to send a coupon only to shoppers who bought a specific SKU.  To do this, we have AMPscript that checks the SKU and if the SKU is found, the coupon is inserted.

However, what we're finding is that a coupon is always assigned and only displays in emails for those who bought the SKU in question...but we're going to run out of coupon codes if we keep doing it this way.

We tried to nest the AMPscript, but it appears the script is first rendered.

Some of our code:

```
%%[SET @orderid = AttributeValue('OrderID')
   SET @Date = Now()
   SET @SKU = AttributeValue('ItemList') 

IF IndexOf(@SKU,'617232') > 0 THEN]%%

%%=ClaimRowValue("CouponCodes_OrderReceipt20180927","CouponCode","IsClaimed", ,"JobID",JobID,"ListID",ListID,"EMAIL_ADDRESS_",emailaddr,"OrderID",@orderID)=%%

%%[ELSE]%%
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

How do we make it so a coupon is assigned only if the SKU is in the list of purchased products??!?!

Comment: Whats in ItemList Data Extension field? Is it some comma delimited skus?

Comment: Basically, yes.

Comment: I should also add -- The coupon creative is not directly in the email, but is referenced as a content segment, and the coupon was still claiming rows even when the AMPscript prevented the content from loading.

Concatenating the content call (i.e., 'mycontents\coupon')=%%) also didn't work - it just shows the copy in the email and not the coupon.

Answer (score 0):

We figured out a workaround, and frankly is painfully easy and should have been more obvious.

We maintain the code to display the coupon only to those who genuinely qualify.

However, we added AMPscript to force the recipient's **email address** and **orderID** if they did not genuinely qualify (and the coupon isn't displayed anyway).  We're effectively re-issuing the coupon over and over again.

Here's the AMPscript:

```
%%=ClaimRowValue("CouponCodes_TESTLIST","CouponCode","IsClaimed", ,"JobID",JobID,"ListID",ListID,"EMAIL_ADDRESS_",@email,"OrderID",@orderID)=%%
```

and

```
%%[SET @orderid = AttributeValue('OrderID')
   SET @Date = Now()
   SET @Item = AttributeValue('ItemList')

 IF @Date > '09/26/2018 22:00:00' AND @Date < '10/03/2018 22:00:00' AND IndexOf(@Item,'617231') < 1 THEN
    SET @email = "test@test.com"
    SET @orderID = "111111"

  ELSE 
    SET @email = AttributeValue('EmailAddress')
    SET @orderID = AttributeValue('OrderID')

  ENDIF]%%

%%[IF @Date > '09/26/2018 22:00:00' AND @Date < '10/03/2018 22:00:00' AND IndexOf(@Item,'617231') > 0 THEN]%%
<tr><td>%%=ContentAreaByName("my contents\coupon\Order_CouponTest")=%%</td></tr>

%%[ELSE]%%
%%[ENDIF]%%
```